# pm2 error on nodejs-express-typeorm application, Error: Module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm, pm2, node.js-typeorm

I have node-express-typeorm application that I want to run with pm2.
`pm2 start app.js` seems to work fine and it shows the app as online. However when a request is made to the server it returns connection refused, app runs well without pm2 but I need it for load balancing and autorestart on crash. I checked pm2 logs and it says module not found.

```
19|app     | Error: Cannot find module '../entity/User'
19|app     | Require stack:
19|app     | - C:\Users\khuranac\Documents\GitHub\Construction-Job-Board\backend\src\dao\UserDao.js
19|app     | - C:\Users\khuranac\Documents\GitHub\Construction-Job-Board\backend\src\routes\loginRoute.js
19|app     | - C:\Users\khuranac\Documents\GitHub\Construction-Job-Board\backend\app.js
19|app     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
19|app     |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (C:\Users\khuranac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\require-in-the-middle\index.js:81:25)
19|app     |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
19|app     |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\khuranac\Documents\GitHub\Construction-Job-Board\backend\src\dao\UserDao.js:3:18)
19|app     |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
19|app     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
19|app     |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
19|app     |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
19|app     |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
19|app     |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (C:\Users\khuranac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\require-in-the-middle\index.js:101:39) {
19|app     |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
19|app     |   requireStack: [
19|app     |     'C:\\Users\\khuranac\\Documents\\GitHub\\Construction-Job-Board\\backend\\src\\dao\\UserDao.js',
19|app     |     'C:\\Users\\khuranac\\Documents\\GitHub\\Construction-Job-Board\\backend\\src\\routes\\loginRoute.js',
19|app     |     'C:\\Users\\khuranac\\Documents\\GitHub\\Construction-Job-Board\\backend\\app.js'
19|app     |   ]
19|app     | }
```

Here is the User.ts file

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn, OneToMany, ManyToOne, CreateDateColumn, Long} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

    constructor(){
    
    }
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    @Column()
    name: string;
    
    @Column()
    createdAt: Date;
    
    @Column()
    phone_number: string
    
    @Column("mediumtext")
    address: string
    
    @Column()
    postalCode: string

}
```

UserDao file

```
const { User } = require("../entity/User");

const { DB_Connection } = require("../../db_connection/typeormConnection");

class UserDao {
constructor() {
this.connection = new DB_Connection();
}
}
```

I chnaged the require statement to  `const { User } = require("../entity/User.ts");` But pm2 logs another error on the import statement in User.ts

```
20|app     | import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn, OneToMany, ManyToOne, CreateDateColumn, Long} from "typeorm";
20|app     | ^^^^^^
20|app     |
20|app     | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
20|app     |     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
20|app     |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
20|app     |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
20|app     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
20|app     |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
20|app     |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
20|app     |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
20|app     |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (C:\Users\khuranac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\require-in-the-middle\index.js:101:39)
20|app     |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
20|app     |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\khuranac\Documents\GitHub\Construction-Job-Board\backend\src\dao\UserDao.js:3:18)
```

I dont understand why its not working It seem to be working fine without pm2 with no errors.